# Debugging Jersey Unmarshalling Error - Bad Request syntactically incorrect

Tags: rest, glassfish, xml-parsing, jersey

I am building a REST Webservice with the help of Jersey on Glassfish. Now I am struggeling with my custom input Source for my searchQuerys.

If have a search Method:

```
@POST
@Path("search")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Index> search(SearchQuery searchqry) {
   ...
}
```

And the Class SearchQuery:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SearchQuery implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SearchQuery() {
    }

    public SearchQuery(float lat, float lng) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public float getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(float lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public float getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(float lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    private float lat;
    private float lng;
}
```

And my call:

```
curl -v -X POST --data-binary "<SearchQuery><lat>3.3</lat><lng>5.4</lng></SearchQuery>" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/resources/index/search
```

I tried a restconsole to send the XML request, but I get the same error:

> HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request
>
> ---
>
> **type** Status
>   report
>
> **message**Bad Request
>
> **des cription**The
>   request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Bad
>   Request).
>
> ---
>
> #### GlassFish Server Open Source Edition
>   3.1.2
>
> * Closing connection #0

I am missing something essentially or can somebody give me a hint how to debug the unmarshalling part inside the Application Server?

I followed the guide at http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/12/30/example-of-restful-webservice-with-xml-and-json-using-maven-jaxb-jersey-tomcat-and-curl/
and tested varius combination of Annotations but no sucess :(

Comment: You're returning a List of Index objects. Is this class (Index) serializable, and marked with @XMLRootElement?

Comment: @BWitched jep, i also tested the Method with void as returnvalue, still dont work :(

Comment: Maybe you've already tried but, have you captured the http package sent (o better, the one which arrives the server)? Just to make sure that it's 100% correct. Another idea, I've had some problems with Jersey that got solved adding a "/" at the begining of the path: @Path("/search")

Comment: It look like you need to provide the correct content type for the server: `curl ... -H "Content-Type: application/xml"`.

Comment: @dma_k i already send the ContentType in my curl statement at the end, +Bwitched tested it with /search, still nothing, i will continue to test with whireshark and see whats posted to the server.

Comment: Ah, sorry, haven't noticed that. I would suggest then to increase log level and see where it breaks. Maybe starting debugging from top servlet would be more efficient...

Comment: Does anyone know how to get jersey to log meaningful messages about unmarshalling errors? That would probably be the best answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINALLY** found the real reason for my problem:
**SearchQuery** is mapped to "**searchQuery**" inside XML

**TESTClass** is mapped to **tESTClass** inside the XML Entity