# Android error : MultipartEntity , request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpclient, multipartentity

I am suppose to send song (mp3/wav) file and some data through secure restful web service. I am using MultipartEntity to make HttpPost request. but When I execute it through HttpClient, the server replies this error

**HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request
type: Status report
message : Bad Request
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Bad Request).**

But the service is doing very well if we call it from its Web interface. please help

its the code

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost();
        try {
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

            reqEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody("test@testmail.com"));
            reqEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody("123"));
            reqEntity.addPart("title", new StringBody("My new song"));
            reqEntity.addPart("musicData", new FileBody(new File(FilePath))); 

            // FIlePath is path to file and contains correct file location

            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

            postRequest.setURI(new URI(ServiceURL));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.e("URISyntaxException", e.toString());
        }
```

I also included  apache-mime4j, httpclient, httpcore and httpmime jars for MultipartEntity.

This is HTML page snap for the Service.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the authentification works?

Comment: Can you post your mapping URL too in your web service? It could be that your URL request is different than you've mapped.

Comment: I checked URL its correct and working in HTML page ... but that code for Android is giving error

Comment: Are you sure names `email`, `musicData`, etc. are correct, with regards to lower/upper case?

Comment: yes ..... its correct, I double check it

Comment: Are you sure that the authentication is not using the header parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the setURI method and passing the URL in when you create your HttpPost object, as follows. This worked for me ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164451/654870)).

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(ServiceURL);
try {
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

    reqEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody("test@testmail.com"));
    reqEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody("123"));
    reqEntity.addPart("title", new StringBody("My new song"));
    reqEntity.addPart("musicData", new FileBody(new File(FilePath)));     
    postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);

} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    Log.e("URISyntaxException", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: just accept it because bounty time has ended and that we some how near solution but the problem is still there :(

Answer (score 3):

It seems header of the request is incorrect, this problem can occur if you use a [different Auth protocol](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-117291.html?s=2c205dbb00bbae93045110a00c1f355b) or [upper/lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660311/debugging-jersey-unmarshalling-error-bad-request-syntactically-incorrect) or simply [wrong things in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049783/the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect) that server side can't handle.

Answer (score 2):

Dont waste your time by trying different different combinations.There are some HTTP Request tools available for HTTP with which you can track request and response you are getting.Ex. HTTP Analyzer download trial version

Call URL from your working webinterface , copy request and response
then do same with from program the tool is enogh capable to capture your request and response data.

Now compare working and non working request you will surely able to dignose the issue whether it can be header issue or some authentication related issue.